# Showing Recent Messages Undefined symbol: _il2cpp_add_internal_call

Tags: unity-game-engine, xcode15

i am using unity 2023.2.3 and xcode 15.0.1. my problem is while i trying to build iOS project in xcode i am getting below errors[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kaEk.jpg)

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_il2cpp_add_internal_call", referenced from:
scripting_add_internal_call(char const*, void const*) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_array_class_get", referenced from:
scripting_array_class_get(ScriptingClassPtr, unsigned long) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_array_element_size", referenced from:
scripting_array_element_size(ScriptingClassPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_array_length", referenced from:
scripting_array_length(ScriptingArrayPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
scripting_array_length_safe(ScriptingArrayPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_array_new", referenced from:
scripting_array_new(ScriptingClassPtr, unsigned long, unsigned long) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_assembly_get_image", referenced from:
MonoManager::LoadAssemblies() in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_Scripting_3_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_class_array_element_size", referenced from:
scripting_class_array_element_size(ScriptingClassPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_class_enum_basetype", referenced from:
scripting_class_enum_basetype(ScriptingClassPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_class_from_name", referenced from:
scripting_class_from_name(ScriptingImagePtr, char const*, char const*) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
MonoManager::GetScriptingClass(char const*, char const*, char const*) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_Scripting_3_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_class_from_system_type", referenced from:
scripting_class_from_systemtypeinstance(ScriptingSystemTypeObjectPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_class_from_type", referenced from:
scripting_class_from_type(ScriptingTypePtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_class_get_assemblyname", referenced from:
scripting_class_get_assemblyname(ScriptingClassPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)
"_il2cpp_class_get_declaring_type", referenced from:
scripting_class_get_declaring_type(ScriptingClassPtr) in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_ScriptingBackend_Il2Cpp_0_4ia5l.o)

i have been searching for almost one week i couldn't find any proper solution

Answer (score 0):

May be your are not using this method in your code but some components on prefab  have referenced it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).